# How can I use AMA(Advance Mobile Access) custom authentication with OAuth service provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

How can I use AMA custom authentication with OAuth service provider?

Perhaps, the AMA doc of [Implementing Bluemix Single Sign On as a custom  in identity provider.](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/id_provs/index-gentopic2.html#custom_idaas) in [Getting started](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/index.html) could help this. But this doc has deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not support Single Sign On.

Using Advanced Mobile Acces(AMA) custom authentication involves 2 steps.

In the first step, you have to configure the authentication mechanism to access the backend services and this is done in the AMA dashboard of the backend application.  Please see the sub-section **Configuring an authentication mechanism for back end access**  in the document Advanced Mobile Access Configuration page section [Registering your Advanced Mobile Access Client App](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/client/index-gentopic1.html#register_app) for details on configuring the custom authentication mechanism.  Basically, you will be providing the url of the custom identity provider page that will handle authentication challenge.

In the second step, you have to configure the client app to use custom authentication and please see the document section
[Using a custom identity provider](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/id_provs/index-gentopic2.html#custom_id_prov) 
for procedure to do it.

Comment: can AMA be used with Facebook AND google for same app? After I add facebook in AMA dashboard, I don't see how I can also add google...

Answer (score 0):

Did you navigate down below FB and Google auth on that link you provided?
There is a doc on [using a custom identity provider](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/security/id_provs/index-gentopic2.html#custom_idaas)

Comment: Yes, I know that. There were

Comment: There was a document "Implementing Bluemix Single Sign On as a custom in identity provider." in  "using a custom identity provider" you mentioned. I found this  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/188285/ama-with-ibm-sso-an-invalid-secret-was-provide-for.html . According to above, This doc was for Bluemix SSOv1 which was deleted on Jan.